# Display data in footer for all pages

Tags: php, symfony

I added some scripts in my HomeController to import data from my database and diplay it in my homepage footer. Like that :

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Template(":frontend:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $social_manager = $this->get('socialLink_manager');
        $socials = $social_manager->getSocials();
        return [
            'socials' => $socials
        ];
    }
```

But in other pages I can't find my data. So, I duplicate the same code in the other controller to have the same data in my footer. I want to do this one time and have the same thinks in all pages.

Comment: Can you print the value of: `$social_manager`

Comment: Take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers Basically end up with a footer controller that can be called from all your templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your footer just call a new controller action:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:social')) }}
```

The new controller action:

```
# src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function socialAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $socials = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Social')->getAll();

        return $this->render('default/social.html.twig', array(
            'socials' => $socials,
        ));
    }
```

and default/social.html.twig:

```
#{# app/Resources/views/default/social.html.twig #}

<ul>
    {% for social in socials %}
        <li>{{ social.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```